# Why is html route not working in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So it's a pretty trivial question...
I have a get request in my client code.

```
function tosurvey(){$.get( "/survey", d=>d?console.log("Redirected"):false);}
```

And a listener on the back

```
 router.get('/survey', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('survey.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
    });
```

However, it doesn't work. If you go directly to /survey, it does work, but get request is pointing to /survey too and should be happening onclick as it is binded to click event on the front.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "doesn't work"?

Comment: I basically wanted to have urls prettytyped

Comment: That doesn't explain at all what "doesn't work" means, and offers no information about what the client-side code is for.  Why wouldn't you just link to `/survey`?  Why the AJAX?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah, I'm trying to avoid <a href> tags.. node is going to be redirecting from the server... I have both html and api routes... this was for the html routes

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question doesn't make any sense at all.  I guess it's a non-issue if you've got this working for what you're trying to do, but if you could explain a bit more, it may help others in the future.  What exactly are you doing on the client, and why?  Why are you checking the response data?  And, you say "redirected", but you're not actually redirecting anything on your server... you're just returning an HTML file.  And, why would you avoid using links on your page?

Comment: Hey Brad, I was just doing html and api routes, and this was an html route returning an html file. I know that I could have just done an <a href>, but I did not want to do it that way.  Also, it had to do with prettytyping urls without having directories with index.html files.

Comment: Might I suggest...   https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite  Then you can use `express.static()` as well, and save yourself a lot of hassle later.

Comment: Thanks for urlrewrite, and I am using express.static already to bind css and front end js to html rendered by node

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it.

```
    let x = window.location.pathname;
    x=x.split("/");
    x.pop();
    x=x.join('/');
   $.get("/", d=>d?(console.log("Redirected"),window.location=x+'/'):false);
```

Comment: Actually, for public static content, it'd be better to use `serve-static` middleware, which is what it seems the goal is of that route.

Comment: Some explanation of what you changed and why would be helpful to those who come find your answer later.

Comment: `const serveStatic = require('serve-static');` ... then later on, you'd do something like: `app.use('/survey', serveStatic('public'))`

Comment: serve-static was already used. this issue was different (not related to serve-static)

Comment: basically I just wanted to (at the end of the day) pretty-type urls without htmls at the end

Comment: usually what I do for that is I still use `serve-static` and then let the front-end framework handle the client routing. For example, in angularjs, I use ui-router and I can have clean routes like: 'survey/form' and 'survey/results'. The other advantage is the client side codebase can grow independently of whatever the server is. I tend to keep server-side routes for handling api requests, like, "submitResults()". But it's all subjective

Comment: RichS great idea, but I have jquery on the front :)